# Detecting when a window is focused by clicking the taskbar or using Alt + Tab

Tags: winapi, focus, foreground

I would like to be able to detect when a window gains focus by the user clicking on the taskbar or by cycling to the window with Alt + Tab. Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not. Why do you need to know that ?

Comment: Why do you care about those particular actions? It is possible to operate the taskbar with the keyboard. Why discriminate against users that use the keyboard? There are various events and hooks that tell you when windows gain focus, become activated etc.

Comment: Sounds like you have decomposed your problem into two problems: A trivial one, and an impossible one. You are now asking for help with the impossible one. Why don't you ask about the real issue you are trying to solve instead of your proposed solution? Of course you could register a [WinEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373889.aspx) callback and listen for `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS`. But that won't give you any information, how the object gained input focus. I'm pretty sure, you aren't even interested about input focus (rather than window activation).

Comment: @IInspectable You are right. I was referring to window activation. I am automating certain tasks in the other window when it becomes activated, but I don't want to perform the action if they click on the window to activate it.

Comment: But if they activate it with they keyboard then you want to carry on? Or indeed some other user input device.  What is special about the mouse?

Comment: A CBT hook via `SetWindowsHookEx()` will tell you if a window is being activated by mouse or not.